# Order of inclusion and interpretation for php and html

Tags: php, html, include

I am trying to display different content on a page based on some options.

Also, I am trying to avoid using php echo for all the html output.

I came up with the following solution accidentally, and now I'm confused about how it actually works.

> test.php

```
<?php
    function get_content() {
        $page = 0;

        if($page == 0)
            include('page0.php');
        else
            include('page1.php');
    }
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php echo get_content() ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

> page0.php

```
<?php
    $link = "http://www.google.ca";
    $name = "GOOGLE";
?>
<a href="<?= $link ?>"> <?= $name ?> </a>
```

> page1.php

```
<?php
    $link = "http://www.yahoo.ca";
    $name = "YAHOO";
?>
<a href="<?= $link ?>"> <?= $name ?> </a>
```

It seems like the php interpreter would end up including html tags into a `<?php ?>` block when it reaches the following line, but somehow, this code works, and the outputted html is valid.

```
include('page0.php');
```

Can someone explain what exactly is going on here?

Comment: Another clue.. In the following question, the accepted answer includes html files directly into a php block: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/180501/which-is-better-to-include-html-inside-php-code-or-outside-it

Comment: for anyone interested, php also has something called "here documents". A tutorial can be found here: http://jungels.net/articles/php-templates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
>   executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end
>   tags.

From [PHP manual, include function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).